# CGI implementation or altenative?

Tags: cgi

This question is very basic; but I am confused so please I am sorry if you are irritated. I just know that CGI is a standard/protocol.

1> Is mod_(perl/python/ruby) an implementation of CGI or is it an alternative?
2> If it is an alternative then, conceptually, is it similar to Java Servlets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_(perl/python/ruby) is an alternative to CGI - the `mod_[somebinding]` apache modules try to avoid the performance penalty of CGI by using Apache's native interfaces.

The analogon between `mod_[somebinding]/Apache` and `Servlets/Java Application Server` is valid, but I would prefer something like

```
Webserver -> mod_[somebinding] -> Library in somebinding

Webserver -> Java Application Server -> Servler
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the CGI is a interface standart, and mod_* is modules for Apache Http Server. 
For example, you can use CGI ( FastCGI or SCGI ) with any language and under any web server. 
The alternative in Ruby world is application servers like Unicorn which is used by guys from GitHub.

Comment: So you mean that mod_* are implementations of the CGI.

Comment: No, as @Eugen Rieck mentioned before, it is completly orthogonal to cgi. For example mod_perl is just embeding the perl interpriter to apache.